# How to store JSON data for my application

Tags: html, json

I am building a website, which tracks the number of corona virus cases my country. The data is stored in the following  structure in the file: `cases.json`

```
{
  day: {
    city: {
      cases: 1
          }
       }
}
```

How can i access this data in index.html file to display it a my table.

Comment: You're going to need JavaScript to import the JSON file into the HTML. Shows us some of the code to understand better what you want to accomplish.

Comment: What are you using? javascript, php, react?
Be more specific.

Comment: What's expected result? What was tried so far? What are client's libraries and plugins used?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this in pure `JavaScript` in your `index.html` file:

1. assign your file data to a variable in the `cases.json` file as follows:

```
data={
  day: {
    city: {
      cases: 1
          }
       }
}
```

2. Include the file in your `head`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cases.json"></script>
```

3. Then, you can use it as follows:

```
console.log(data)
```

Comment: What if i store the data in index.js as java script object and use DOM querry sector to insert data into correct rows of the table.

Comment: Yes, you can easily do this. But the above solution was presented according to your case. One advantage of storing it in a file like you're doing though would be accessing the data in several files.

Comment: JSON.parse(data), where would this line be used?

Comment: When accessing the data from the file in case it was read as a string. You may only use ``data`` if it was read as an ``Object``.